PowerApps flow Response action returns boolean instead
I have a PowerApps Canvas App and I use a flow to get a JSON from an API. In the flow I use the HTTP action to get the json. In an response - request action I return the body of the HTTP action. When I test the flow in PowerAutomate I see that it returns the expected JSON. But when I use the flow in my PowerApp the return value is boolean and there are no properties to access.
In PowerApps I call it like this:
ClearCollect(myVar, myFlow.Run())

In PowerAutomate the reponse has this JSON:
{
  "type": "Response",
  "kind": "Http",
  "inputs": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "@outputs('HTTP')?['body']"
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "JSON_analysieren": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}


Do you want the whole JSON to be returned to your PowerApp? + If u can share a snapshot of your PowerAutomate that will be helpful

I was having this problem today. If I called the flow from a new canvas app, it would return a table, but from the app I was working on, the flow would return a boolean.
I tried a restart of everything I could think of, and it resolved the issue. Here's what I did:

Closed everything and restarted my PC
Removed the flow from my app, re-added the flow, and refreshed it
Delete the line that called the flow, saved and refreshed the window, and re-added the line

This combination immediately fixed the issue. I hope it fixes yours, and that we both never have it again!
